# Interrupting Colab Keras model training and calling it again consumes all memory and causes runtime to crash

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I have Keras CNN model in Colab and during training it consumes about half of the memory. If I interrupt the training and then restart it, Colab cashes because all memory is used. Is there a way to clear memory or solve this problem,

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to restart the kernel and clean the output? You can select either Restart runtime or Factory reset runtime, check both.

[image]

Comment: I don't want to restart the runtime, I just want to clear the memory used by the interrupted training.